# as3 - figure out the variable type from an empty variable

Tags: actionscript-3, class, dynamic

Is it possible to figure out the variable type when the variable isn't instantiated?

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
var foo:ExampleOne;
var bar:ExampleTwo;

var arr:Array = [foo, bar];

for each(var myVar:Object in arr)
{
    myClass = new getDefinitionByName( getQualifiedClassName( myVar ) ) // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the variables are a reference to objects that are not created in the vm until you create them using the "new" keyword. So until you do this, the references (foo/bar etc) will always be null no matter what operation you're running on them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you want to do, but you could may be use `describeType` :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.utils.describeType;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;


    public class TestTextfield extends Sprite
    {
        public var foo:TextField;
        public var bar:ByteArray;

        public function TestTextfield()
        {
            var arr:Array = ["foo", "bar"];

            for each(var myVar:String in arr)
            {
                var varClass : String = describeType(this)..variable.(@name == myVar).@type.toString();
                var myClass : * = new (getDefinitionByName(varClass) as Class)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, it does not work. I downvoted for posting an answer without testing.

Comment: It works ^^', that's why I put all file structure, I've just tested on flash builder

Comment: I'll happily upvote to cancel the downvote, though I note that you put "foo" and "bar" in quotes, which is cheating! ;) AFAIK it's not possible the way originally asked.

Comment: That's right, I cheat but I think this is the closest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "className" property.

It should return "TextInput", "Button", etc... depending the case

```
for each (var item:* in myArray)
{
    if(item.hasProperty('className'))
    {
        trace("item ["+i+"] is :" + item['className']);
    }
}
```

Comment: item is null so you can't access anything inside the variable.

Comment: Ok.. then the question is:   what type is <nothing> ?   there is one solution... there is no type.

Comment: I know but the variable is declared so I though I could retrieve this information.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to do something like this ?

```
var a:Class = MyClassA; //put a reference to a Class object into 'a' variable
var b:Class = MyClassB;

var classes:Array = [a,b];

for each(var classObj:Class in classes){
  var objInstance : * = new classObj()
}
```